# Yarn,Npm İnstall Expo Start Error React Native :/

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I Get This Error While Installing The Ready System
I Get React Native Error When I Start Expo

""
yarn install
yarn install v1.22.18
warning ....\package.json: No license field
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning " > lottie-react-native@5.0.1" has unmet peer dependency "lottie-ios@^3.2.3".
warning "react-native > react-native-codegen > jscodeshift@0.11.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/preset-env@^7.1.6".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...

```
success Saved lockfile.
Done in 37.42s.

C:\Users\isimsiz\Desktop\V1.0.0>yarn global add expo-cli
yarn global v1.22.18
warning ..\..\package.json: No license field
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning "xo > eslint-import-resolver-webpack@0.13.2" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@>=1.11.0".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...

success Installed "expo-cli@5.3.2" with binaries:
      - expo
      - expo-cli
Done in 19.80s.

yarn global v1.22.18ktop\V1.0.0>yarn global add eas-cli
warning ..\..\package.json: No license field
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning "xo > eslint-import-resolver-webpack@0.13.2" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@>=1.11.0".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Installed "eas-cli@0.51.0" with binaries:
      - eas
Done in 17.36s.
```

""

Expo Start :( Eroor

```
    Using node to generate images. This is much slower than using native packages.
› Optionally you can stop the process and try again after successfully running `npm install -g sharp-cli`.

Using node to generate images. This is much slower than using native packages.
› Optionally you can stop the process and try again after successfully running `npm install -g sharp-cli`.

Using node to generate images. This is much slower than using native packages.
› Optionally you can stop the process and try again after successfully running `npm install -g sharp-cli`.

Web Bundling complete 105940ms
./node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Components/TextInput/TextInputState.js:18:17
Module not found: Can't resolve '../../Utilities/Platform'
  16 |
  17 | const React = require('react');
> 18 | const Platform = require('../../Utilities/Platform');
     |                 ^
  19 | const {findNodeHandle} = require('../../Renderer/shims/ReactNative');
  20 | import {Commands as AndroidTextInputCommands} from '../../Components/TextInput/AndroidTextInputNativeComponent';
  21 | import {Commands as iOSTextInputCommands} from '../../Components/TextInput/RCTSingelineTextInputNativeComponent';
./node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js:14:17
Module not found: Can't resolve '../../Utilities/Platform'
  12 |
  13 | const BatchedBridge = require('../../BatchedBridge/BatchedBridge');
> 14 | const Platform = require('../../Utilities/Platform');
     |                 ^
  15 | const Systrace = require('../../Performance/Systrace');
  16 |
  17 | const invariant = require('invariant');
./node_modules/@stripe/stripe-react-native/lib/module/components/StripeProvider.js:1:515
Module not found: Can't resolve '../../package.json'
> 1 | var _interopRequireDefault=require("@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault");Object.defineProperty(exports,"__esModule",{value:true});exports.StripeProvider=StripeProvider;exports.initStripe=void 0;var _regenerator=_interopRequireDefault(require("@babel/runtime/regenerator"));var _defineProperty2=_interopRequireDefault(require("@babel/runtime/helpers/defineProperty"));var _react=require("react");var _NativeStripeSdk=_interopRequireDefault(require("../NativeStripeSdk"));var _helpers=require("../helpers");var _package=_interopRequireDefault(require("../../package.json"));function ownKeys(object,enumerableOnly){var keys=Object.keys(object);if(Object.getOwnPropertySymbols){var symbols=Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(object);if(enumerableOnly){symbols=symbols.filter(function(sym){return Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(object,sym).enumerable;});}keys.push.apply(keys,symbols);}return keys;}function _objectSpread(target){for(var i=1;i<arguments.length;i++){var source=arguments[i]!=null?arguments[i]:{};if(i%2){ownKeys(Object(source),true).forEach(function(key){(0,_defineProperty2.default)(target,key,source[key]);});}else if(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors){Object.defineProperties(target,Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(source));}else{ownKeys(Object(source)).forEach(function(key){Object.defineProperty(target,key,Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(source,key));});}}return target;}var EXPO_PARTNER_ID='pp_partner_JBN7LkABco2yUu';var repository=_package.default.repository;var appInfo={name:(0,_helpers.shouldAttributeExpo)()?_package.default.name+"/expo":_package.default.name,url:repository.url||repository,version:_package.default.version,partnerId:(0,_helpers.shouldAttributeExpo)()?EXPO_PARTNER_ID:undefined};var initStripe=function initStripe(params){var extendedParams;return _regenerator.default.async(function initStripe$(_context){while(1){switch(_context.prev=_context.next){case 0:extendedParams=_objectSpread(_objectSpread({},params),{},{appInfo:appInfo});_NativeStripeSdk.default.initialise(extendedParams);case 2:case"end":return _context.stop();}}},null,null,null,Promise);};exports.initStripe=initStripe;function StripeProvider(_ref){var children=_ref.children,publishableKey=_ref.publishableKey,merchantIdentifier=_ref.merchantIdentifier,threeDSecureParams=_ref.threeDSecureParams,stripeAccountId=_ref.stripeAccountId,urlScheme=_ref.urlScheme,setUrlSchemeOnAndroid=_ref.setUrlSchemeOnAndroid;(0,_react.useEffect)(function(){if(!publishableKey){return;}if(_helpers.isAndroid){_NativeStripeSdk.default.initialise({publishableKey:publishableKey,appInfo:appInfo,stripeAccountId:stripeAccountId,threeDSecureParams:threeDSecureParams,urlScheme:urlScheme,setUrlSchemeOnAndroid:setUrlSchemeOnAndroid});}else{_NativeStripeSdk.default.initialise({publishableKey:publishableKey,appInfo:appInfo,stripeAccountId:stripeAccountId,threeDSecureParams:threeDSecureParams,merchantIdentifier:merchantIdentifier,urlScheme:urlScheme});}},[publishableKey,merchantIdentifier,stripeAccountId,threeDSecureParams,urlScheme,setUrlSchemeOnAndroid]);return children;}
    |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   ^
  2 | //# sourceMappingURL=StripeProvider.js.map
./node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Alert/Alert.js:13
Module not found: Can't resolve '../Utilities/Platform'
  11 | 'use strict';
  12 |
> 13 | import Platform from '../Utilities/Platform';
  14 | import NativeDialogManagerAndroid, {
  15 |   type DialogOptions,
  16 | } from '../NativeModules/specs/NativeDialogManagerAndroid';
./node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/NativeExceptionsManager.js:60:17
Module not found: Can't resolve '../Utilities/Platform'
  58 | }
  59 |
> 60 | const Platform = require('../Utilities/Platform');
     |                 ^
  61 |
  62 | const NativeModule = TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing<Spec>(
  63 |   'ExceptionsManager',
./node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/setUpDeveloperTools.js:13
Module not found: Can't resolve '../Utilities/Platform'
  11 | 'use strict';
  12 |
> 13 | import Platform from '../Utilities/Platform';
  14 |
  15 | declare var console: typeof console & {_isPolyfilled: boolean, ...};
  16 |
./node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ReactNativeVersionCheck.js:13
Module not found: Can't resolve '../Utilities/Platform'
  11 | 'use strict';
  12 |
> 13 | import Platform from '../Utilities/Platform';
  14 | const ReactNativeVersion = require('./ReactNativeVersion');
  15 |
  16 | /**
./node_modules/react-native/Libraries/EventEmitter/NativeEventEmitter.js:13
Module not found: Can't resolve '../Utilities/Platform'
  11 | 'use strict';
  12 |
> 13 | import Platform from '../Utilities/Platform';
  14 | import EventEmitter from '../vendor/emitter/EventEmitter';
  15 | import {type EventSubscription} from '../vendor/emitter/EventEmitter';
  16 | import RCTDeviceEventEmitter from './RCTDeviceEventEmitter';
./node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image/AssetSourceResolver.js:24:17
Module not found: Can't resolve '../Utilities/Platform'
  22 |
  23 | const PixelRatio = require('../Utilities/PixelRatio');
> 24 | const Platform = require('../Utilities/Platform');
     |                 ^
  25 |
  26 | const invariant = require('invariant');
  27 |
./node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ReactNative/PaperUIManager.js:14:17
Module not found: Can't resolve '../Utilities/Platform'
  12 |
  13 | const NativeModules = require('../BatchedBridge/NativeModules');
> 14 | const Platform = require('../Utilities/Platform');
     |                 ^
  15 | const UIManagerProperties = require('./UIManagerProperties');
  16 |
  17 | const defineLazyObjectProperty = require('../Utilities/defineLazyObjectProperty');
./node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ReactPrivate/ReactNativePrivateInterface.js:32:11
Module not found: Can't resolve '../Utilities/Platform'
  30 |   },
  31 |   get Platform(): Platform {
> 32 |     return require('../Utilities/Platform');
     |           ^
  33 |   },
  34 |   get RCTEventEmitter(): RCTEventEmitter {
  35 |     return require('../EventEmitter/RCTEventEmitter');
./node_modules/react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet/processColor.js:13:17
Module not found: Can't resolve '../Utilities/Platform'
  11 | 'use strict';
  12 |
> 13 | const Platform = require('../Utilities/Platform');
     |                 ^
  14 |
  15 | const normalizeColor = require('./normalizeColor');
  16 |
./node_modules/react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet/processTransform.js:14:17
Module not found: Can't resolve '../Utilities/Platform'
  12 |
  13 | const MatrixMath = require('../Utilities/MatrixMath');
> 14 | const Platform = require('../Utilities/Platform');
     |                 ^
  15 |
  16 | const invariant = require('invariant');
  17 | const stringifySafe = require('../Utilities/stringifySafe').default;
./node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Utilities/HMRClient.js:16:17
Module not found: Can't resolve './Platform'
  14 | const invariant = require('invariant');
  15 | const MetroHMRClient = require('metro-runtime/src/modules/HMRClient');
> 16 | const Platform = require('./Platform');
     |                 ^
  17 | const prettyFormat = require('pretty-format');
  18 |
  19 | import getDevServer from '../Core/Devtools/getDevServer';
./node_modules/react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet/processColor.js:34:31
Module not found: Can't resolve './PlatformColorValueTypes'
  32 |
  33 |   if (typeof normalizedColor === 'object') {
> 34 |     const processColorObject = require('./PlatformColorValueTypes')
     |                               ^
  35 |       .processColorObject;
  36 |
  37 |     const processedColorObj = processColorObject(normalizedColor);
./node_modules/react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet/normalizeColor.js:24:35
Module not found: Can't resolve './PlatformColorValueTypes'
  22 | ): ?ProcessedColorValue {
  23 |   if (typeof color === 'object' && color != null) {
> 24 |     const {normalizeColorObject} = require('./PlatformColorValueTypes');
     |                                   ^
  25 |     const normalizedColor = normalizeColorObject(color);
  26 |     if (normalizedColor != null) {
  27 |       return color;
./node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Alert/Alert.js:17
Module not found: Can't resolve './RCTAlertManager'
  15 |   type DialogOptions,
  16 | } from '../NativeModules/specs/NativeDialogManagerAndroid';
> 17 | import RCTAlertManager from './RCTAlertManager';
  18 |
  19 | export type AlertType =
  20 |   | 'default'
./node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network/XMLHttpRequest.js:18:22
Module not found: Can't resolve './RCTNetworking'
  16 | const EventTarget = require('event-target-shim');
  17 | const GlobalPerformanceLogger = require('../Utilities/GlobalPerformanceLogger');
> 18 | const RCTNetworking = require('./RCTNetworking');
     |                      ^
  19 |
  20 | const base64 = require('base64-js');
  21 | const invariant = require('invariant');
./components/AdmobBanner.jsx:6
Module not found: Can't resolve 'expo-ads-admob'
  4 | import { useStateValue } from "../StateProvider";
  5 |
> 6 | import {
  7 |   AdMobBanner,
  8 |   setTestDeviceIDAsync,
  9 |   requestPermissionsAsync,
./screens/HomeScreen.jsx:3
Module not found: Can't resolve 'expo-ads-admob'
  1 | /* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
  2 | /* eslint-disable no-undef */
> 3 | import { requestPermissionsAsync, getPermissionsAsync } from "expo-ads-admob";
  4 | import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback, useRef } from "react";
  5 | import {
  6 |   View,
./node_modules/@react-navigation/drawer/lib/module/views/DrawerView.js:22
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-native-reanimated'
  20 |   View,
  21 | } from 'react-native';
> 22 | import * as Reanimated from 'react-native-reanimated';
  23 | import { useSafeAreaFrame } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
  24 |
  25 | import type {
./node_modules/@react-navigation/drawer/lib/module/views/legacy/Drawer.js:12
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-native-reanimated'
  10 |   View,
  11 | } from 'react-native';
> 12 | import Animated from 'react-native-reanimated';
  13 |
  14 | import type { DrawerProps } from '../../types';
  15 | import DrawerProgressContext from '../../utils/DrawerProgressContext';
./node_modules/@react-navigation/drawer/lib/module/views/legacy/Overlay.js:3
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-native-reanimated'
  1 | import * as React from 'react';
  2 | import { Platform, Pressable, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
> 3 | import Animated from 'react-native-reanimated';
  4 |
  5 | const {
  6 |   // @ts-expect-error: this is to support reanimated 1
./node_modules/@react-navigation/drawer/lib/module/views/modern/Drawer.js:15
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-native-reanimated'
  13 |   State as GestureState,
  14 | } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
> 15 | import Animated, {
  16 |   interpolate,
  17 |   runOnJS,
  18 |   useAnimatedGestureHandler,
./node_modules/@react-navigation/drawer/lib/module/views/modern/Overlay.js:3
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-native-reanimated'
  1 | import * as React from 'react';
  2 | import { Platform, Pressable, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
> 3 | import Animated, {
  4 |   useAnimatedProps,
  5 |   useAnimatedStyle,
  6 | } from 'react-native-reanimated';
./node_modules/react-native-draggable-flatlist/lib/constants.js:5:32
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-native-reanimated'
  3 | exports.isReanimatedV2 = exports.isWeb = exports.isAndroid = exports.isIOS = exports.DEFAULT_PROPS = exports.DEFAULT_ANIMATION_CONFIG = exports.SCROLL_POSITION_TOLERANCE = void 0;
  4 | var react_native_1 = require("react-native");
> 5 | var react_native_reanimated_1 = require("react-native-reanimated");
    |                                ^
  6 | // Fire onScrollComplete when within this many px of target offset
  7 | exports.SCROLL_POSITION_TOLERANCE = 2;
  8 | exports.DEFAULT_ANIMATION_CONFIG = {
./node_modules/react-native-draggable-flatlist/lib/procs.js:23:45
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-native-reanimated'
  21 | Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
  22 | exports.springFill = exports.setupCell = exports.hardReset = exports.getIsAfterActive = void 0;
> 23 | var react_native_reanimated_1 = __importStar(require("react-native-reanimated"));
     |                                             ^
  24 | var constants_1 = require("./constants");
  25 | var set = react_native_reanimated_1.default.set, cond = react_native_reanimated_1.default.cond, add = react_native_reanimated_1.default.add, sub = react_native_reanimated_1.default.sub, block = react_native_reanimated_1.default.block, eq = react_native_reanimated_1.default.eq, neq = react_native_reanimated_1.default.neq, and = react_native_reanimated_1.default.and, divide = react_native_reanimated_1.default.divide, greaterThan = react_native_reanimated_1.default.greaterThan, greaterOrEq = react_native_reanimated_1.default.greaterOrEq, Value = react_native_reanimated_1.default.Value, spring = react_native_reanimated_1.default.spring, lessThan = react_native_reanimated_1.default.lessThan, lessOrEq = react_native_reanimated_1.default.lessOrEq, multiply = react_native_reanimated_1.default.multiply;
  26 | if (!react_native_reanimated_1.default.proc) {
./node_modules/react-native-draggable-flatlist/lib/components/DraggableFlatList.js:43:45
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-native-reanimated'
  41 | var react_1 = __importStar(require("react"));
  42 | var react_native_gesture_handler_1 = require("react-native-gesture-handler");
> 43 | var react_native_reanimated_1 = __importStar(require("react-native-reanimated"));
     |                                             ^
  44 | var CellRendererComponent_1 = __importDefault(require("./CellRendererComponent"));
  45 | var constants_1 = require("../constants");
  46 | var PlaceholderItem_1 = __importDefault(require("./PlaceholderItem"));
./node_modules/react-native-draggable-flatlist/lib/components/CellDecorators.js:28:45
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-native-reanimated'
  26 | var react_1 = __importDefault(require("react"));
  27 | var react_native_1 = require("react-native");
> 28 | var react_native_reanimated_1 = __importStar(require("react-native-reanimated"));
     |                                             ^
  29 | var draggableFlatListContext_1 = require("../context/draggableFlatListContext");
  30 | var useNode_1 = require("../hooks/useNode");
  31 | var useOnCellActiveAnimation_1 = require("../hooks/useOnCellActiveAnimation");
./node_modules/react-native-draggable-flatlist/lib/components/ScrollOffsetListener.js:3:32
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-native-reanimated'
  1 | "use strict";
  2 | Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
> 3 | var react_native_reanimated_1 = require("react-native-reanimated");
    |                                ^
  4 | var utils_1 = require("../utils");
  5 | var ScrollOffsetListener = function (_a) {
  6 |     var scrollOffset = _a.scrollOffset, onScrollOffsetChange = _a.onScrollOffsetChange;
./node_modules/react-native-draggable-flatlist/lib/components/PlaceholderItem.js:24:45
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-native-reanimated'
  22 | var react_1 = __importStar(require("react"));
  23 | var react_native_1 = require("react-native");
> 24 | var react_native_reanimated_1 = __importStar(require("react-native-reanimated"));
     |                                             ^
  25 | var animatedValueContext_1 = require("../context/animatedValueContext");
  26 | var draggableFlatListContext_1 = require("../context/draggableFlatListContext");
  27 | var propsContext_1 = require("../context/propsContext");
./node_modules/react-native-draggable-flatlist/lib/components/CellRendererComponent.js:38:45
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-native-reanimated'
  36 | var react_1 = __importStar(require("react"));
  37 | var react_native_1 = require("react-native");
> 38 | var react_native_reanimated_1 = __importStar(require("react-native-reanimated"));
     |                                             ^
  39 | var draggableFlatListContext_1 = require("../context/draggableFlatListContext");
  40 | var constants_1 = require("../constants");
  41 | var useCellTranslate_1 = require("../hooks/useCellTranslate");
./node_modules/react-native-draggable-flatlist/lib/context/animatedValueContext.js:24:32
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-native-reanimated'
  22 | exports.useAnimatedValues = void 0;
  23 | var react_1 = __importStar(require("react"));
> 24 | var react_native_reanimated_1 = require("react-native-reanimated");
     |                                ^
  25 | var react_native_gesture_handler_1 = require("react-native-gesture-handler");
  26 | var useNode_1 = require("../hooks/useNode");
  27 | var react_2 = require("react");
./node_modules/react-native-draggable-flatlist/lib/hooks/useAutoScroll.js:41:32
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-native-reanimated'
  39 | exports.useAutoScroll = void 0;
  40 | var react_1 = require("react");
> 41 | var react_native_reanimated_1 = require("react-native-reanimated");
     |                                ^
  42 | var react_native_gesture_handler_1 = require("react-native-gesture-handler");
  43 | var constants_1 = require("../constants");
  44 | var useNode_1 = require("../hooks/useNode");
./node_modules/react-native-draggable-flatlist/lib/hooks/useOnCellActiveAnimation.js:4:32
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-native-reanimated'
  2 | Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
  3 | exports.useOnCellActiveAnimation = void 0;
> 4 | var react_native_reanimated_1 = require("react-native-reanimated");
    |                                ^
  5 | var animatedValueContext_1 = require("../context/animatedValueContext");
  6 | var cellContext_1 = require("../context/cellContext");
  7 | var procs_1 = require("../procs");
./node_modules/react-native-draggable-flatlist/lib/hooks/useSpring.js:16:32
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-native-reanimated'
  14 | exports.useSpring = void 0;
  15 | var react_1 = require("react");
> 16 | var react_native_reanimated_1 = require("react-native-reanimated");
     |                                ^
  17 | var constants_1 = require("../constants");
  18 | function useSpring(_a) {
  19 |     var _b = _a === void 0 ? { config: constants_1.DEFAULT_ANIMATION_CONFIG } : _a, configParam = _b.config;
./node_modules/react-native-draggable-flatlist/lib/hooks/useCellTranslate.js:4:32
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-native-reanimated'
  2 | Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
  3 | exports.useCellTranslate = void 0;
> 4 | var react_native_reanimated_1 = require("react-native-reanimated");
    |                                ^
  5 | var animatedValueContext_1 = require("../context/animatedValueContext");
  6 | var refContext_1 = require("../context/refContext");
  7 | var procs_1 = require("../procs");
./node_modules/react-native-youtube-iframe/dist/WebView.web.js:1:202
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-native-web-webview'
> 1 | Object.defineProperty(exports,"__esModule",{value:true});Object.defineProperty(exports,"WebView",{enumerable:true,get:function get(){return _reactNativeWebWebview.WebView;}});var _reactNativeWebWebview=require("react-native-web-webview");
    |                                                                                                                                                                                                          ^
./node_modules/@openspacelabs/react-native-zoomable-view/src/ReactNativeZoomableView.tsx 39:2
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (39:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders`enter code here`
|   originalPageX: null,
|   originalPageY: null,
> } as ReactNativeZoomableViewState;
|
| class ReactNativeZoomableView extends Component<
Error from chokidar (C:\): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\hiberfil.sys
```